# Orion Context Broker Performance Testing

Tags: fiware-orion

I've been doing some performance testing on Orion Context Broker sending many POST requests to update an attribute inside an entitiy and then check that the subscriptors receive the message correctly. The environment that I built is shown in the next image [Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMO8R.png)

To deploy all the components in my server I'm using docker and they comunicate to each other as in an internal network(docker network). A sensor is simulated with a script that send data to Orion. If I want to send 800 post requests per minute, I send a request each 0.075s(60/800).
With the default configuration of Orion(using the docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/) when the number of request is around 800, Orion fails and then I receive an *"Empty reply from server".*  I understand that this happens because the default mode for notifications is **trasient** and this is not suitable for high load scenarios.
I've tried changing the default parameters building another orion image using **threadpool mode** and test diferent numbers for *n*(number of workers) and *q*(queue limit), for example n=8 and q=80, and changed the **reqPoolSize** to 8(I am working on a machine with 8 cores and 8GB RAM). But now, with around 500 alerts Orion hungs for a few minutes and then works well. I checked the other components in the environment and they seem to be working right. Are there another parameter that I should be looking at, or shoud I keep testing more numbers for the ones that I'm using?